# Привязка button к правому краю

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

Суть вопроса. Есть у меня ListBox, который я задаю вот так:

```
<ListBox Name="serviceListBox"  SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="505" Margin="13,46,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183" 
                 Background="#FF181818" ItemsSource="{Binding source}" Grid.Column="1">

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Ellipse
                        Width="16"
                        Height="16"
                        Fill="{Binding IndicatorBrush}" />
                        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                        <Button Content="►" Name="srvStart" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsEnabled="{Binding AntiIsChecked}"
                                Click="srvStart_Click"/>
                        <Button Content="⬛" Name="srvStop" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked}" 
                                Click="srvStop_Click"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

В нем есть две кнопки, которые нужно привязать к вравому краю листбокса. Слева текст, справа кнопки. Я задаю `HorizontalAlignment="Right"` , но ничего не получается. Помогите.

Comment: `StackPanel` - это последовательный вывод элементов друг за другом, без позиционирования их. Вы можете в нем максимум что сделать, так это выбрать как элементы будут идти (горизонтально или вертикально). Если вам надо занять все пространство и позиционировать каждый элемент по своему "углу", то используйте `Grid` или `DockPanel`, где первый позволяет разделить все на отдельные участки (сетку), а второй позволяет позиционировать объекты при помощи `DockPanel.Dock` свойства. Также не забывайте, что по умолчанию у `ListBox` выравнивание контента идет по левой части!